# How to get unknown field names in PDI?

Tags: pentaho, pdi

In PDI, various transformations may put data (in fields) into the "Result", kind of like copying a dataset in a KTR to a clipboard, so it can be used in the parent job or a downstream sister KTR.

When a `Get rows from result` step hops to a `Copy rows to result` step, multiple fields can join on the `Copy rows to result` step even if they have different field names, data types, and quantity of fields. Usually Spoon complains at design time if field names from different incoming hops aren't identical, but not in that case. Even at runtime, there is no complaint. Example:

[image: Example where exogenous rows can ghost newer rows]

If I can guess which KTR was the very first in execution to use a `Copy rows to result` step, then in another transformation I can use another `Get rows from result` step and a UDJC step containing `get(Fields.In, "FirstName")` to retrieve that field which was in the Result, as one would expect.

Using the Result this way is very useful, but in my use case the incoming field names from `Get rows from result` such as "FirstName" cannot be predicted, having originated literally anywhere, even from a web service that can send whatever it likes, so no solution will work that requires me to type "FirstName" anywhere at design time, which I believe metadata injection requires (?) according to the examples of it I've seen, but the PDI documentation on metadata injection sounds like word salad to me so not sure.

Anyway, I can use a `Get rows from result` step followed by a `Write to log` step wherever I like with no fields specified and the Print headers checkbox marked. That prints each field name in the log (along with the row's values for each field) without me having typed "First Name" anywhere.

All of this is for context, but the core question is... Is it possible to get field header names from Result into a stream or variable instead of just printed to the log?

Seems like this should be quite simple, but have failed to find any information about this.

If I were to use another method like metadata injection, seems like the same principle and same question would apply. Maybe the answer to my question is "Detect fields in Result just like you detect fields in any stream", in which case I would be asking, "How do I detect what fields are present in a stream without knowing what they might be ahead of time"?

Comment: I can't understand what you mean, I don't think you are using the Get rows from result and Copy rows to result correctly, or maybe I haven't understood what you are doing. Maybe you can provide an example? Also, have you tried using metadata injection? Maybe that could be more simple for what you are trying to do

Comment: Hi, thanks. I updated the question to clarify various details, mentioned metadata injection, and added an example.

Comment: "Usually Spoon complains at design time if field names from different incoming hops aren't identical, but not in that case. Even at runtime, there is no complaint."

I've just tried in a transformation adding a "Get rows" and "Data grid" streams as input for a "Copy rows to result" and Spoon DOES warn about adding mixed rows.

If you have in "Get rows" this: ColNumber1, ColString2 and in "Full names" this: ColString3, joining both streams will get you two different types of rows, maybe adding with a Merge join the cols from "Full names" to the Get rows makes more sense.

Comment: Looking at the sample job "Evaluate result rows" from PDI installation I think I understand a bit more what you are doing, the UDJC step you refer is a Javascript job entry perhaps, not a transformation step?

Comment: So you have different types of rows with different column names as input for a transformation, coming from different sources/transformations, and you want to process them using one unique transformation for the different sources. For that you need to get the column names you are going to get. OK, first question, do you have a problem generating a temporary file just with input data? Using a transformation with "Get rows from result" and then a "Text file ouput" would be the easiest way to start processing the rows.

Comment: UDJC = User Defined Java Class, so it contains java rather than javascript. It is a transformation step type in PDI. It can be found in the Design tab within the Scripting section. I could create a text file. Then I guess I could use metadata injection or something special to get the column names back into PDI in a stream. (I say "special" because reading in a text file in a normal way yields a stream with unknown field names.) But is a text file really the best way in PDI for doing something as simple as getting the column names from an existing stream? I'd be better off starting from scratch

Comment: About lack of complaints from PDI, I'm using Spoon 8.3.0.3 and it even executes without error locally, so long as I use the first set of field names. Also runs without complaint on a Jenkins server. Even conflicting data types get mushed into 1 set of fields. For example, I can add a field named "myFunInteger" to the stream, as data type "Integer" with a value 123999, and then in a UDJC in another KTR after the implicit join on `Copy rows to result`, I can use `long fun = Long.valueOf(get(Fields.In, "givenName").getString(r));` to retrieve it from the String field "givenName". LOL, works fine.

Comment: About using a temporary text file to get the columns to inject metadata, that's the solution I use usually (or metadata I have loaded in the database). I'm not a java or javascript developer, so I avoid using UDJC or the other java steps whenever I can. You seem to know Java, so you might be able to work it out. There isn't a step created to do it, so you'll have to create the code.

Comment: About PDI executing without errors the join of both streams to the Write to log, yes, probably it's the only step it won't complain, probably because it doesn't expect a stream structure, so you can write whatever you pass to the step. Just keep in mind that is not the usual way to join streams in PDI, normal steps expect streams with the same structure.

Comment: Thanks very much for your time, Ana. 
If there's no built-in step to get stream field names, I'm open to using a UDJC if someone knows how.